# Track down where alert is being fired from?

Tags: javascript, debugging, trace

I'm mucking through the de-minified CKFinder source looking for where an `alert` is being fired. I forced files to be renamed on upload, and now it's reminding me each time a file is uploaded when it doesn't actually matter.

I've gone through and commented out each `alert` but it's still doing it. Refreshed cache also, and confirmed via Chrome Inspector. Is there any way to figure out what file/line this specific alert is coming from?

Comment: Notepad++ "Find in Files" works wonders in these cases.

Comment: I pretty much did that in ST2, I'm wondering more if there's a way to do it with Inspector, like you can drill into the HTML.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to redefine alert, then put a breakpoint.  or call console.trace

```
alert = function(mesg) {console.trace(mesg)}
```

Comment: Or better yet: `window.alert = function(msg) { debugger; }`

Comment: There aren't enough likes in the world for this.